# Convert Bracket (negative) to double

Tags: c#

Hello How do i Convert a negative value that's in bracket format to double. Currently I have this.

```
Payment.Text = Calc_Payment().ToString("#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)");
```

That converts the payment to Bracket format But I want to do the reverse. String in bracket format to Double. If anyone could help please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
// using System.Globalization
double d = double.Parse("(1,000.90)", NumberStyles.AllowParentheses | 
                                      NumberStyles.AllowThousands | 
                                      NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint)

/* d = -1000.9 */
```

Ref. [Double.Parse Method (String, NumberStyles)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); [NumberStyles Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**NOTE:**
 Money values are better handled by the 'decimal' type. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx):

> Compared to floating-point types, the **decimal** type has more precision
>   and a smaller range, which **makes it appropriate for financial and
>   monetary calculations**.

Comment: Damn, beat me to it :) I was going to say "Leverage the framework" and post more or less the same code, I copped out and just used NumberStyles.Any

Comment: :-)  BTW, I added a note about using `decimal` instead of `double` for money values.